# Cannot open GUI applications with XQuartz mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, remote-access, xquartz

I am using xquartz to login to an Ubuntu server from a Mac machine. After logging in using `ssh -X <username>@<ip>` command, I am trying to launch `nautilus` but it keeps giving the following error:

`Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused`

`(nautilus:14914): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:05:38.090: cannot open display: 0:0`

Ideally, xquartz should have set the appropriate display accordingly. But some problem is happening. I also tried the following command:

`launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.macosforge.xquartz.startx.plist`

but no success.

Answer (score 2):

Verify your (OS/X)XQuartz installation

```
$> brew info xquartz
xquartz: 2.8.1 (auto_updates)
https://www.xquartz.org/
/usr/local/Caskroom/xquartz/2.8.1 (103.5MB)
...
```

Verify your .ssh_config:

```
$> cat .ssh/config
Host *
    ForwardX11 yes
    ForwardX11Trusted yes
    ForwardAgent yes
```

Start your X11 app or service:

```
$> launchctl start org.xquartz.startx

$> launchctl list | grep -i quart
96701   -9  org.xquartz.startx
```

Export your X11 Server:

```
$> export DISPLAY=:0
```

Connect to your remote host and test:

```
$> ssh -Y remote_host
Last login: Mon Apr 26 13:14:01 2021 from host
$> xclock
```